# npm package csvtojson CSV Parse Error: Error: unclosed_quote

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, parsing-error, csvtojson

- Node version: v10.19.0
- Npm version: 6.13.4
- Npm package csvtojson [Package Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)

  ```
  csvtojson({
   "delimiter": ";",
   "fork": true
  })
  .fromStream(fileReadStream)
  .subscribe((dataObj) => {
  console.log(dataObj);
  }, (err) => {
  console.error(err);
  }, (success) => {
  console.log(success);
  });
  ```

While trying to handle large CSV file (about 1.3 million records) I face error "**CSV Parse Error: Error: unclosed_quote.**" after certain records(e.g. after 400+ records) being processed successfully. From the CSV file i don't see any problems with data formatting there, however the parser might be raising this error because of "\n" character being found inside the column/field value.

- Is there a solution already available with this package? or
- is there a workaround to handle this error? or
- is there a way to skip such CSV rows having any sort of errors not only this one, to let the
  entire CSV to JSON parsing work without the processing getting stuck?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it impossible to fix the input CSV?

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: Can't change the input CSV looking at the bulk of records that it contains, so i did not not solve it yet, badly need to get this working.

Comment: If the /n is causing the issue maybe you can create readable stream of the csv pipe it to a transform function that will remove the character and then pipe it to csvtojson.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played about with this, and it's possible to hook into this using a CSV File Line Hook, [csv-file-line-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#csv-file-line-hook), you can check for invalid lines and either repair or simply invalidate them.

The example below will simply skip the invalid lines (missing end quotes)

**example.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");

let fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream("test.csv");
let invalidLineCount = 0;

const csvtojson = require("csvtojson");
csvtojson({ "delimiter": ";", "fork": true })
.preFileLine((fileLineString, lineIdx)=> {
    let invalidLinePattern = /^['"].*[^"'];/;
    if (invalidLinePattern.test(fileLineString)) {
        console.log(`Line #${lineIdx + 1} is invalid, skipping:`, fileLineString);
        fileLineString = "";
        invalidLineCount++;
    }
    return fileLineString
})
.fromStream(fileReadStream) 
.subscribe((dataObj) => { 
    console.log(dataObj);
}, 
(err) => { 
    console.error("Error:", err); 
}, 
(success) => {
    console.log("Skipped lines:", invalidLineCount);
    console.log("Success"); 
});
```

**test.csv**

```
Name;Age;Profession
Bob;34;"Sales,Marketing"
Sarah;31;"Software Engineer"
James;45;Driver
"Billy, ;35;Manager
"Timothy;23;"QA
```

Comment: Use of "preFileLine" helped to get rid of error "CSV Parse Error: Error: unclosed_quote.".

.preFileLine((fileLineString, lineIdx)=> {
    let invalidLinePattern = /^['"].*[^"'];/;
    if (invalidLinePattern.test(fileLineString)) {
        console.log(`Line #${lineIdx + 1} is invalid, skipping:`, fileLineString);
        fileLineString = "";
        invalidLineCount++;
    }
    return fileLineString
})


Thanks @terry Lennox

Comment: Excellent, glad to see it helped!

Comment: could you tell me how to use this code in with your code to export (save) the test.csv as test.json file? 
fs.writeFile('users.json', JSON.stringify(fileLineString, null, 4), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("JSON array is saved.");
});

Answer (score 0):

This regex works better

> /^(?:[^"\]|\.|"(?:\.|[^"\])*")*$/g

Here is a more complex working script for big files by reading each line

```js
import csv from 'csvtojson'
import fs from 'fs-extra'
import lineReader from 'line-reader'

import { __dirname } from '../../../utils.js'

const CSV2JSON = async(dumb, editDumb, headers, {
    options = {
        trim: true,
        delimiter: '|',
        quote: '"',
        escape: '"',
        fork: true,
        headers: headers
    }
} = {}) => {
    try {
        log(`\n\nStarting CSV2JSON - Current directory: ${__dirname()} - Please wait..`)

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let firstLine, counter = 0
            lineReader.eachLine(dumb, async(line, last) => {
                counter++

                // log(`line before convert: ${line}`)
                let json = (
                    await csv(options).fromString(headers + '\n\r' + line)
                        .preFileLine((fileLineString, lineIdx) => {
                            // if it its not the first line
                                // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                                if (counter !== 1 && !fileLineString.match(/^(?:[^"\\]|\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*")*$/g)) {
                                    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                                    console.log(`Line #${lineIdx + 1} is invalid. It has unescaped quotes. We will skip this line.. Invalid Line: ${fileLineString}`)
                                    fileLineString = ''
                                }

                            return fileLineString
                        })
                        .on('error', e => {
                            e = `Error while converting CSV to JSON.
                            Line before convert: ${line}
                            Error: ${e}`
                            throw new BaseError(e)
                        })
                )[0]

                // log(`line after convert: ${json}`)

                if (json) {
                    json = JSON.stringify(json).replace(/\\"/g, '')

                    if (json.match(/^(?:[^"\\]|\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*")*$/g)) {
                        await fs.appendFile(editDumb, json)
                    }
                }

                if (last) {
                    resolve()
                }
            })
        })
    } catch (e) {
        throw new BaseError(`Error while converting CSV to JSON - Error: ${e}`)
    }
}

export { CSV2JSON }
```